Git says my branch is ahead of origin - even after revert/reset
On a recently cloned project, I just now made an unintentional change/commit to my local main branch.  (I had intended to create and check out a new feature branch for the change, but I wasn't thinking :-)).
Upon realizing my mistake, I reverted the change.  While this did indeed set my code back to the state it was in before I changed it, running git status nonetheless indicated that my branch was a commit ahead of the origin (i.e. the hosted repo).
No problem, I thought: I'll just do a git reset --hard.  Nope, that didn't work - my console still shows that I was ahead of origin.  I also tried git reset --hard head.  Still no luck.  And multiple times during this process I ran git pull origin main, to no effect.
My question is: how to I rid my git history of these commits, so that git status shows me as being completely in sync with origin?

I'm sure this is what you want: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30555797/git-move-commits-to-different-branch-and-make-master-same-as-upstream-master-br Found in https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+move+commits+different+branch

The command git reset --hard HEAD would just reassign HEAD to itself and delete any staged or unstaged changes.
You want to use the command
git reset --hard HEAD~2

The argument HEAD~2 shifts your HEAD reference behind by two commits (the unwanted commit and the revert commit). Once done, a git status should show complete sync with the origin.

When you created a new commit on the main branch, you moved your local history one commit ahead the remote main's history.
After that, when you performed a revert, you actually added another new commit on your local main with the inverse changes introduced by your last commit. This is why the content of your working directory was again like before your accidental commit, but the history was ahead (by 2 commits) than the one on the remote.

Given one or more existing commits, revert the changes that the related patches introduce, and record some new commits that record them.

Furthermore, performing git reset --hard HEAD only resets your index and working directory to the commit pointed by the HEAD symref (i.e. main's head commit). This is why nothing changed. You simply reset your index and working directory to the current situation. According to git reset --hard documentation:

Resets the index and working tree. Any changes to tracked files in the working tree since  are discarded. Any untracked files or directories in the way of writing any tracked files are simply deleted.

At this point, if you want to revert your history on your main branch while preserving your new commit on a new branch, you could perform:
# create a new branch pointing to the commit before the revert
git branch new-branch main~

# make sure to be on the main branch
git checkout main

# reset the main branch to its remote counterpart
git reset --hard origin/main

# or alternatively, reset main by 2 commits (the accidental one and the revert)
# git reset --hard main~2


The reason reset doesn't work is because

main is a local branch, and the branch you currently is on, it is pointing to exactly where you are. So you reset to your current location.
HEAD means the branch you are currently on, which in this case translates to main. See above :P

What you can do is reset to the version of main which your remote is pointing to.

git reset --hard origin/main (main on origin)
git reset --hard @{u} (your current branch's upstream branch)

